# How to return std::vector from a function using C++11 move semantics?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics, copy-elision

I know C++11 has move semantics from this link:
[Elements of Modern C++ Style](http://herbsutter.com/elements-of-modern-c-style/)

But it does not introduce how to return a vector using move semantics. How to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Like this:

```
std::vector<std::string> make_a_vector_of_strings()
{
    std::vector<std::string> result;

    // just an example; real logic goes here
    result.push_back("Hello");
    result.push_back("World");

    return result;
}
```

The operand of the return statement is eligible for copy elision, and if the copy is not elided, the operand is considered for the move-constructor of the return type, so everything is as good as it can be.

Comment: I see some posts said using std::vector<std::string> && as return type, or return move(result). All these confusing me!

Comment: @DeanChen: Both of these ideas sound completely wrong.

Comment: I think you should qualify that `result` is only moved in the return-statement since it's a local variable / parameter. If `result` was a data member (or global, eww), it would not be moved.

Comment: @dyp: if `result` weren't a local variable, the code would still Do The Right Thing, since then it would be aliased and we wouldn't want to mutate an aliased value surreptitiously without express request to do so.

Comment: Indeed, but I fear that your answer may be misunderstood: One might think that a return-statement always moves its operand.

Comment: @dyp: Maybe. Once I see the first SO question about someone expecting a move from a return statement when there is none I might start mentioning this.